# jQuery function stops working after opening and closing modal window

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have this script which is currently working to turn off and on "likes" on my page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.like').click(function () {
        $(this).not(this).removeClass('click');
        $(this).toggleClass("click");
    });
});
</script>
```

But when I open a modal window that contains html (with the same script on this page currently), and then close it, the function has stopped working on the underlying page. The "like" buttons no longer work.

One more bit of info, this is an AngularJS app with (currently) very simple modules. I'm sure the problem can be solved in Angular (any solutions are welcome), but I wanted to at least get the jQuery working first before translating it.

Here is the modal window HTML:

```
<div class="popup-input">
    <div class="feed-box">
        <div class="photo-submit">
            <a href="#" id="photo"><img src="images/pic1-large.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="comments">
          <div class="comment">
            <a class="avatar">
                <div class="center">
                    <img src="images/meg.jpg">
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="post-content">
              <a class="author">Meg Robichaud</a>
              <div class="metadata pull-right">
                <div class="date">
                  <ul class="margin-zero">
                    <li><a href=""><img src="images/reply.png" alt="Add Photo" id="reply"></a></li>
                    <li><div class="like"></div></li>
                    <li class="time-posted">25m</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            My view this morning is simply beautiful... <a href="">instagram.com/p/mV0PUrHRwQ/</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-wrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Reply..." class="reply" maxlength="30">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--  TOGGLE FUNCTION LIKE BUTTON -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.like').click(function () {
        $(this).not(this).removeClass('click');
        $(this).toggleClass("click");
    });
});
</script>
```

If I don't have the script in this separate html file it won't load when I open the modal (I know there must be a better solution than doubling up on the script).

Here is the script that loads the modal window:

```
<!-- MODAL IMAGE POPUP -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#photo').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $.get('image.html', function(data){
            modal.open({content: data});
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And lastly, here is the pop-up window modal script file being referenced:

```
var modal = (function(){
  var 
  method = {},
  $overlay,
  $modal,
  $content,
  $close;

        // Center the modal in the viewport
        method.center = function () {
          var top, left;

          top = Math.max($(window).height() - $modal.outerHeight(), 0) / 2;
          left = Math.max($(window).width() - $modal.outerWidth(), 0) / 2;

          $modal.css({
            top:top + $(window).scrollTop(), 
            left:left + $(window).scrollLeft()
          });
        };

        // Open the modal
        method.open = function (settings) {
          $content.empty().append(settings.content);

          $modal.css({
            width: settings.width || 'auto', 
            height: settings.height || 'auto'
          });

          method.center();
          $(window).bind('resize.modal', method.center);
          $modal.show();
          $overlay.show();
        };

        // Close the modal
        method.close = function () {
          $modal.hide();
          $overlay.hide();
          $content.empty();
          $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
        };

        // Generate the HTML and add it to the document
        $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        $modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>');
        $content = $('<div id="content"></div>');
        $close = $('<a id="close" href="#">close</a>');

        $modal.hide();
        $overlay.hide();
        $modal.append($content, $close);

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('body').append($overlay, $modal);           
        });

        $close.click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          method.close();
        });

        return method;
      }());

      // Calls
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#message').click(function(e) {
          $.get('popup-form.html', function(data){
            modal.open({content: data});
          });
        });

        $('#test').click(function(e) {
          $.get('popup-form.html', function(data){
            modal.open({content: data});
          });
        });

        $('a#photo').click(function(e){
          modal.open({content: "Hows it going?"});
          e.preventDefault();
        });


      });
```

Comment: What does this line of code do? $(this).not(this).removeClass('click');

Comment: I'm also unable to think of a time when $(this).not(this) would actually return an element. Sort of like if(true === false).

Answer (score 1):

The modal is contained within the current page (same DOM), and any script you load through the modal will carry to the underlying page.

If you use a delegated event on the "main page", it should work in the modal too.

```
$(document).on('click', '.like', function(e) { ... });
```

This would mean that you can skip the script in the modal, and save yourself a double bind (the probable offender).

But I'm also a bit confused over your use of `$(this).not(this)`. `this` is the clicked element, so you're essentially saying *get clicked element (jQueryfied), but not the clicked element*. It reads wrong to me, and I think you mean to do this instead:

```
$('.click').not(this).removeClass('click');
```

This will remove any class named `click`, from all elements containing said class **except** from the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

I just passes event to click function, and use **event.preventDefault()**. for stop the current event propogation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.like').click(function (event) {
            $(this).not(this).removeClass('click');
            $(this).toggleClass("click");
    event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```